# Issue in form submit with the Integration of HDIV　and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hdiv

I integrated HDIV and Spring MVC. Now I need to submit a form to the server. The problem is Ｉ　need to give the submit button a name like "btnSave" or "btnSubmit". So that I can make request mapping like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", params = "btnSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

and I render the submit button like this:

```
<input name="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Now HDIV will gives the error message: `INVALID_PARAMETER_NAME` about btnSave.

I know I can exclude paramter btnSave in the HDIV  configuration, but I am just wondering if there is any better solution. I have a lot of forms with different submit buttons on them and I dont want to put all of them into the HDIV configuration of paramsWithoutValidation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Spring MVC's tag for submit.

```
<form:button value="Save" name="btnSave">Save</form:button>
```

I hope it helps.